# Create bar chart where the X axis is the dataset columns using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset taken from a poll using Likert scale and I would like the columns of the dataset to be the X axis of a bar chart. How can I do using ggplot2?

This is my dataset:

```
> dput(head(externos))
structure(list(FE1 = c(5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L), FE2 = c(4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, 4L), FE3 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L), UE1 = c(4L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L), UE2 = c(5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L), UE3 = c(4L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L), UE4 = c(5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), AE1 = c(5L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), AE2 = c(5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), IE1 = c(5L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L), IE2 = c(5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like it to be like this (mean by category):

[image]

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: You'll need to reshape (pivot) your data into a long format to work with it in `ggplot2`. I don't know exactly how you expect to transform *that* data into *that* graph, I don't see the aggregation or such that'll do that. There are plenty of good tutorials and such on `ggplot2`, including https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/ which includes good examples of `geom_bar` and similar that may do just what you need.

Comment: How do you want to summarise the multiple values per group? In your output example the values for AE1 and AE2 are the means, but not for AE3. Is the mean per group what you want?

Comment: Exactly, @neilfws! I'm going to use the mean and confidence interval, but at the moment just the mean would be enough.

Comment: RaffaBass, is there a problem with giving us usable data?

Comment: Edited question. I removed the sensitive fields that were in the dataset.